# Is it better to fetch data from database and put into ArrayList before binding it to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, simplecursoradapter

I want to populate RecyclerView using database. As currently there is no inbuilt adapter for populating `RecyclerView` using database, I have used [CursorRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) by Shywim. I have created a sample App to test it and it worked fine. The feature I didn't liked is having an `_id` column in the resultset and calling `swapCursor()`  on each database operation, mostly insert and delete. This goes same with ListView when using `SimpleCursorAdapter`. My query is what if I use ArrayList as the dataset instead of directly using the Cursor.

Benefits of doing this(my assumption)  :

1. No more a need of `_id` column in the resultset.
2. Can fetch the data from database, put it into ArrayList and close the cursor.
3. No need of calling `swapCursor()` on each database operation as I can add/remove specify elements from the ArrayList and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

   I don't know the exact logic behind `swapCursor()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`. So, can't decide which one is light-weight and efficient.

If someone has experienced this or done this before, please clear my doubts. Any corrections and suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: use `CursorRecyclerAdapter`, this is a close brother of `CursorAdapter` in a `ListView`, if it was better / easier to use custom `BaseAdapter` / `ArrayAdapter` google would not create `CursorAdapter` / `ResourceCursorAdapter` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you can even find `SimpleCursorRecyclerAdapter` on the net which has features of `SimpleCursorAdapter`, just google for: `SimpleCursorRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: @pskink : Yes, I am using it. But why there is compulsion of having `_id` column in resultset. I already have some other column as primary key.

Comment: so what is the problem with `_id`? just query: `select my_other_primary_key_column as _id, other_column, yet_another_column where ...`

Comment: @pskink : ok thats fine. But calling `swapCursor()` each time  for database changes won't have any impact on performance ? And how can I take advantage of `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemRemoved()` methods of RecyclerView for animating the changes.

Comment: how often does your database changes? 10 times per second or just based on user interaction (new / delete / change buttons)?

Comment: @pskink : Depends on user interaction and some broadcasts. In the beginning the table will contain 100-200 rows approximately.

Comment: so is it 1 change per second? 10 changes? 100? or rather one change per 10 - 20 seconds?

Comment: @pskink : 1-10 changes per second.

Comment: and you want to animate 10 changes per second???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117903/discussion-between-monish-kamble-and-pskink).

Answer (score -1):

Using array list and custom adapter is better way for this as per my understanding.

See some scenarios below :

**1)** Cursor will close after each transaction so database will work smoothly.

**2)** As you can close cursor on operation done so it will never generate cursor not closed exception.

**3)** You can modify view of each row easily and manage custom adapter as per your choice.

There are many other reasons, but in short custom adapter is better then cursor adapter as per my understanding.